# How to mirror a Mac desktop to a larger Windows computer's screen?

Tags: mac, display, windows, screen, mirroring

I've a 15-inch MacBook Pro and a 21-inch All-in-one Windows Computer.
However, I haven't any HDMI or DisplayPort cable but Ethernet.

I would like to transfer the Mac's desktop to the larger computer display, if possible with the native resolution of the latter (1920x1080), with a keyboard and mouse plugged on the Mac to control it. It is possible, just with LAN or Ethernet? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

[AirServer](http://www.airserver.com) might be worth a try. It's an AirPlay receiver for Mac and PC. So as long as both computers are in the same network, it should allow you to stream your MBP screen through AirPlay to your Windows computer.

I'm not exactly sure how it will handle resolutions though.

Comment: You could also use VNC on the Mac and PC which should allow you to display one computer on another's screen. The only issue here is that keyboard, mouse and video response (though pretty speedy over a local network) might be degraded. Check and see if the manufacturer of that PC has a mode to let it act directly as a monitor, like iMacs do.

Comment: @SteveChambers Very true. Any screen sharing application would achieve the goal, like TeamViewer, JoinMe or Synergy as well. I guess it would depend on how much tolerance the OP has for latency and possibly quality. Media streaming apps tend to be lower latency and better quality than screen sharing or remote control apps, but both approaches are feasible.